# System.DateTime has nested DateTimes in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, .net-6.0

Dealing with nested dates in `System.DateTime`.

In my controller it seems to deserialize the object with nested Dates:

[image]

When I run this line of code I get a stack overflow exception:

[image]

Why does `System.DateTime` field have a nested dates in it, and how can I remove them?

I actually have the same issue with this field:

[image]

The entities:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class DomainEntity<TId> : DomainEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public TId Id { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class DomainEntity 
    {
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedById { get; set; }
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedById { get; set; }
        public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Dto: DomainEntity
    { 
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class VeganItemEstablishmentDto : Dto<int> 
    {
        [Required]
        public int VeganItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int NotInEstablishmentCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int InEstablishmentCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public EstablishmentDto Establishment { get; set; }
        public VeganItemDto VeganItem { get; set; }
        public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    }

    public class VeganItemEstablishmentDto<TVeganItemDto> : VeganItemEstablishmentDto
        where TVeganItemDto : VeganItemDto
    {
        public new TVeganItemDto VeganItem { get; set; }
    }

public class EventItemEstablishmentDto : VeganItemEstablishmentDto<EventItemDto>
{
}
```

My `Startup.cs` file which has various JSON configurations in it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using FirebaseAdmin;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using NetTopologySuite.IO.Converters;
using Npgsql;
using Vepo.Data;
using Vepo.DataContext;
using Vepo.Domain;
using Vepo.Infrastructure;
using Vepo.Services;

namespace Vepo.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
            .AddDbContext<VepoContext>(opt => {
                opt
                .UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration
                    .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
                         o => o.UseNetTopologySuite()
                    )
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .EnableDetailedErrors()
                    .LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    
            services.AddTransient<UserResolverService>();
            
            services.AddTransient<ExtendedVepoContext>();

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new GeoJsonConverterFactory());
            });

            services.AddControllers(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            }).AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
            {
                x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                x.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            }).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new GeoJsonConverterFactory());
            });

            FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("firebase_admin_sdk.json"),
            });

            var claims = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { ClaimTypes.Role, "User" }
            };

            services
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/vepo-165705";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/vepo-165705",
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = "vepo-165705",
                        ValidateLifetime = true
                    };
                });

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
            });

            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGroceryItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(GroceryItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAllVeganItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(AllVeganItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IEventItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(EventItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IFashionItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(FashionItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRecipeItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(RecipeItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGroceryStoreItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(GroceryStoreItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRestaurantItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(RestaurantItemEstablishmentsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IUsersRepository), typeof(UsersRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGroceryItemsRepository), typeof(GroceryItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IEventItemsRepository), typeof(EventItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IFashionItemsRepository), typeof(FashionItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRecipeItemsRepository), typeof(RecipeItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGroceryStoreItemsRepository), typeof(GroceryStoreItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRestaurantItemsRepository), typeof(RestaurantItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IMenuItemsRepository), typeof(MenuItemsRepository));
            services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMenuItemEstablishmentsService, MenuItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IGroceryStoreItemEstablishmentsService, GroceryStoreItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRestaurantItemEstablishmentsService, RestaurantItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventItemEstablishmentsService, EventItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IFashionItemEstablishmentsService, FashionItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRecipeItemEstablishmentsService, RecipeItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IGroceryItemEstablishmentsService, GroceryItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAllVeganItemEstablishmentsService, AllVeganItemEstablishmentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMenuItemsService, MenuItemsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IGroceryStoreItemsService, GroceryStoreItemsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRestaurantItemsService, RestaurantItemsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventItemsService, EventItemsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IFashionItemsService, FashionItemsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRecipeItemsService, RecipeItemsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IGroceryItemsService, GroceryItemsService>();

            services.AddScoped(typeof(IMenuItemEstablishmentsRepository), typeof(MenuItemEstablishmentsRepository));

            services.AddScoped<ISearchService, SearchService>(serviceProvider =>
            {
                return new SearchService(
                        Configuration["elasticEndpoint"],
                        Configuration["elasticUsername"],
                        Configuration["elasticPassword"],
                        Configuration["elasticIndexName"]);
            });

            services.AddScoped<IGroceryItemsSearchIndexService, GroceryItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRecipeItemsSearchIndexService, RecipeItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventItemsSearchIndexService, EventItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IFashionItemsSearchIndexService, FashionItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMenuItemsSearchIndexService, MenuItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRestaurantItemsSearchIndexService, RestaurantItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IGroceryStoreItemsSearchIndexService, GroceryStoreItemsSearchIndexService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAllVeganItemsSearchIndexService, AllVeganItemsSearchIndexService>();

            services.AddAutoMapper(
                typeof(EstablishmentProfile),
                typeof(VeganItemEstablishmentProfile),
                typeof(VeganItemProfile),
                typeof(EventItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(EventItemProfile),
                typeof(FashionItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(FashionItemProfile),
                typeof(RecipeItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(RecipeItemProfile),
                typeof(GroceryItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(GroceryItemProfile),
                typeof(GroceryStoreItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(GroceryStoreItemProfile),
                typeof(RestaurantItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(RestaurantItemProfile),
                typeof(MenuItemEstablishmentProfile), 
                typeof(MenuItemProfile));

            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }

        public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app, 
            IWebHostEnvironment env, 
            VepoContext context, 
            IGroceryItemsSearchIndexService searchIndexService)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseGeoJson();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Test1 Api v1");
            });

            searchIndexService.ReIndex(context, SearchIndexes.All);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a chance the erronous code may be in my DataContext:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Vepo.Domain;
using Vepo.Application;

namespace Vepo.DataContext
{
    public class VepoContext : DbContext
    {
        public VepoContext(DbContextOptions<VepoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

            public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

            public string _currentUserExternalId;
            
            public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
            {
                var user = await User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _currentUserExternalId);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }

                AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(user);

                return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
            }

            public override int SaveChanges()
            {
                var user = User.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == _currentUserExternalId);
                AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(user);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }

                return base.SaveChanges();
            }

            public void AddCreatedByOrUpdatedBy(User user)
            {
                foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
                {
                    if (changedEntity.Entity is DomainEntity entity)
                    {
                        switch (changedEntity.State)
                        {
                            case EntityState.Added:
                                entity.CreatedBy = user;
                                entity.UpdatedBy = user;
                                break;
                            case EntityState.Modified:
                                Entry(entity).Reference(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                                entity.UpdatedBy = user;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("postgis");

            // Metadata

            foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
            {
                if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
                    property.SetMaxLength(256);
            }

            foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(System.DateTime)))
            {
                property.SetColumnType("timestamp");
            }

            foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var prop in et.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (prop.Name == "CreatedDate" || prop.Name == "UpdatedDate")
                    {
                        prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
                    }
                }
            }

            // User

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(user =>
            {
                user.HasKey(usr => usr.Id);
                user.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                user.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
                user.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                user.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
            });

            // Vegan Items

            modelBuilder.Entity<VeganItem>(veganItem =>
            {
                veganItem.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
                veganItem.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                veganItem.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                veganItem.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                veganItem.HasKey(e => e.Id);
                veganItem.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                veganItem.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
                veganItem.Property(e => e.Tags)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
                    );
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<FashionItem>(veganItem =>
            {
                veganItem.Property(e => e.Gender)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Option>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
                    );

                veganItem.Property(e => e.Age)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Option>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
                    );
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItem>(veganItem =>
            {
                veganItem.Property(e => e.Difficulty)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Option>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
                    );
            });

            // Vegan Item Establishments
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItemEstablishment>(giEstablishment => 
            {
                giEstablishment.HasIndex(g => new { g.VeganItemId, g.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
                giEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                giEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                giEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                giEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                giEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<EventItemEstablishment>(eiEstablishment => 
            {
                eiEstablishment.HasIndex(g => new { g.VeganItemId, g.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
                eiEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                eiEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                eiEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                eiEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                eiEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<FashionItemEstablishment>(fiEstablishment => 
            {
                fiEstablishment.HasIndex(g => new { g.VeganItemId, g.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
                fiEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                fiEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                fiEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                fiEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                fiEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItemEstablishment>(riEstablishment => 
            {
                riEstablishment.HasIndex(g => new { g.VeganItemId, g.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
                riEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                riEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                riEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                riEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                riEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryStoreItemEstablishment>(gsiEstablishment => 
            {
                gsiEstablishment.HasIndex(g => new { g.VeganItemId, g.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
                gsiEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                gsiEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                gsiEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                gsiEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                gsiEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemEstablishment>(miEstablishment => 
            {
                miEstablishment.HasIndex(m => new { m.VeganItemId, m.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
                miEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                miEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
                miEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                miEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                miEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });

            // Establishments

            modelBuilder.Entity<Establishment>(establishment =>
            {
                establishment.HasIndex("PlaceId").IsUnique();
                establishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
                establishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                establishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
                establishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            });

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                Converters =
                {
                    new JsonStringEnumConverter()
                }
            };
        }

        public DbSet<VeganItem> VeganItems { get; set; }   
        public DbSet<VeganItemEstablishment> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }        
        public DbSet<GroceryItem> GroceryItems { get; set; }        
        public DbSet<EventItem> EventItems { get; set; }        
        public DbSet<FashionItem> FashionItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipeItem> RecipeItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryStoreItem> GroceryStoreItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RestaurantItem> RestaurantItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Establishment> Establishments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItemEstablishment> MenuItemEstablishments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroceryItemEstablishment> GroceryItemEstablishments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventItemEstablishment> EventItemEstablishments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FashionItemEstablishment> FashionItemEstablishments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipeItemEstablishment> RecipeItemEstablishments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ExtendedContext:

```
namespace Vepo.DataContext {
    public class ExtendedVepoContext
    {
        public VepoContext _context;
        public UserResolverService _userResolverService;

        public ExtendedVepoContext(VepoContext context, UserResolverService userService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userResolverService = userService;
            _context._currentUserExternalId = _userResolverService.GetNameIdentifier();
        }
    }
}
```

Users in the db:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't have a circular reference. It has a `Date` property which also happens to be of type `DateTime` (and of course that value then also has a `Date` property, since that's how that goes -- note that none of these properties return the same *object*). Code that properly handles `DateTime` serialization shouldn't be considering the properties at all, since `DateTime` should be treated as a primitive type, not a custom domain object with individual properties to serialize. (It can be serialized as an ISO 8601 string or as the number of ticks, for example.)

Comment: Your second case may well be a true circular reference, if `User` ultimately inherits from `DomainEntity`, but here it's an actual flaw in your object model. It implies every single `User` is created by a `User`, which obviously can't be true -- there has to be at least one user that was part of the initial setup and not created by any user. You shouldn't be able to chase `CreatedBy` indefinitely, since it should be `null` at some point.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - User.CreatedBy and User.UpdatedBy is always null. I never send user data when creating a user as it is always in an unauthenticated logged out state.

Comment: Well, that's definitely not what your screenshot is showing, so I'd check again (maybe users are serialized as being created by themselves?). If it truly was "always null", you shouldn't be able to keep expanding `CreatedBy` like that -- it would show `null`, not `{Vepo.Domain.User}`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert what should I check to confirm? I have just posted an image of the Users in the DB. If you view my code at this point in my question, does that look problematic?: `modelBuilder.Entity<User>(user =>`

Comment: Stack Overflow makes for a poor venue for interactive debugging sessions and EF definitely isn't my strong suit, so I'll have to bow out.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. I removed CreatedBy, UpdatedBy from DomainEntity so that user simply doesn't have those fields (added a new class `CreatedBySomeone` which extends `DomainEntity`. It seems to have fixed  some things. Not getting any Stack overflow exceptions anymore. Still have infinite inner dates, they just don't cause me any exceptions anymore.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I THINK It must have been the `User` causing that stack overflow exception all along.